# java.lang.runtime Exception : unable to start component

Tags: java, android

I am learning java through a video tutorial but I am having a strange problem I create a class named `OpenedClass` in java and implements two classes.
 One is for `OnClickListener` and 2nd is `OnCheckChangeListener` but when i run the application on emulator it always give me the error for the calling `OnClickListener`.
 The code for my java class is:

```
package com.thenewboston.thenewboston;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OpenedClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

TextView question, test;
Button returnData;
RadioGroup selectionList;
String gotBread;
String setData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send);
    initialize();

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    returnData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    selectionList = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgAnswers);
    selectionList.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    returnData.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent person = new Intent();
    Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
    backpack.putString("answer", setData);
    person.putExtras(backpack);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,person);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (checkedId) {
    case R.id.rCrazy:
        setData = "Probably Right !";
        break;
    case R.id.rSexy:
        setData = "Definitely Right !"; 
        break;
    case R.id.rBoth:
        setData = "Spot On !";
        break;
    }
    test.setText(setData);
}

}
```

and this is the output for logcat:

```
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        activity   ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.thenewboston/com.thenewboston.thenewboston.OpenedClass}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.thenewboston.thenewboston.OpenedClass.initialize(OpenedClass.java:44)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.thenewboston.thenewboston.OpenedClass.onCreate(OpenedClass.java:25)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-05 15:59:54.605: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  ... 11 more
```

as you guys can see that it tells me that the error is on line 44 and the line 44 in my code is

```
        returnData.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I did not understand it at all when I comment this line it will show me the layout when I don't it didn't. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: `returnData` is null. check the id in your layout xml

Comment: thanks Raghunandan your comment help alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments below marcin_j post

```
<Button android:id="@+id/bReturn"  // id is bReturn
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
 android:text="Return" >
</Button>
```

Change this

```
returnData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

to

```
returnData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
```

Comment: @jazzb  i could not post it before i din't know what you had in xml. But the id is wrong hence the NPE

Comment: sir i got it from your above comment on my post and i am really thankfull from the depth of my heart. It is my bad that i didn't post the xml file and once again thanks alot Sir.